# Cordova - Windows UWP hardware back button not functioning

Tags: cordova

Building a Cordova app and testing on Windows. On my Windows phone, the hardware back button does not trigger Cordova's backbutton event, as it should.

I have tried multiple methods to capture the event, but no success so far. Anyone got the answer?

currently the code I have is this:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
// This is supposed to capture the WinJS onbackclick event.
if (WinJS) {
    WinJS.Application.onbackclick = function(e) {
        MyApp.app.navigationManager.back();
        // Return true otherwise it will close app.
        return true;
    }

}

function goBack(event) {
    // Here I handle going back
}
// This is how Cordova says you can listen to the event
document.addEventListener("backbutton", goBack(event), false);

// This is another method using a different method to try to capture the event
if (cordova.platformId == 'windows') {
    Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.addEventListener("backpressed", goBack(event));
}
};
```

None of this is capturing the event: the app always suspends rather than returning to the previous page.